# siunitx align numbers in table with some bold numbers

Tags: siunitx

I have change the bold of numbers to `b` from `bx`.

I found only `10pt` is right align, other fontsize is wrong align, when number format is not
asymmetrical, such as `1234567890.12`.

Or if number format is symmetrical such as `1234567890.1111111111`. All fontsize is right align.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr}{b}{n}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{reset-math-version=false,text-series-to-math=true,group-digits=none}
\begin{document}

\fontsize{12pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=10.2]}
1234567890.12\\
\bfseries 1234567890.12 \\
\boldmath 1234567890.12 \\
1234567890.12\\
\end{tabular}

\fontsize{10pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=10.2]}
1234567890.12\\
\bfseries 1234567890.12 \\
\boldmath 1234567890.12 \\
1234567890.12\\
\end{tabular}

\fontsize{8pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=10.2]}
1234567890.12\\
\bfseries 1234567890.12 \\
\boldmath 1234567890.12 \\
1234567890.12\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr}{b}{n}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{reset-math-version=false,text-series-to-math=true,group-digits=none}
\begin{document}

\fontsize{12pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=10.10]}
1234567890.1111111111\\
\bfseries 1234567890.1111111111 \\
\boldmath 1234567890.1111111111 \\
1234567890.1111111111\\
\end{tabular}

\fontsize{10pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=10.10]}
1234567890.1111111111\\
\bfseries 1234567890.1111111111 \\
\boldmath 1234567890.1111111111 \\
1234567890.1111111111\\
\end{tabular}

\fontsize{8pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=10.10]}
1234567890.1111111111\\
\bfseries 1234567890.1111111111 \\
\boldmath 1234567890.1111111111 \\
1234567890.1111111111\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the luxury of selecting a font whose bold and non-bold numerals have the same width? E.g., Times Roman?

Comment: @Mico I thought of this, but many journals require Computer Modern fonts, so I would like to know if there are any other solutions instead of choosing another font.